# Can I reference other properties inside a jsp localization resource

Tags: java, spring, jsp, localization

I would like to have something like

```
label.terms=Terms and conditions
label.disclaimer=You agree to our<a href='#'>${label.terms}</a>
```

in my localization resource files. That synatx for referencing other properties works in other resource files (e.g. db connection strings), but `${}` isn't parsed in the localization resources.

Is there some way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it exactly like you want, but there is a way around. Create a message like this:

```
header_order_edit=Edit Order {0} for customer {1}
```

Then in your JSP, display the message like this:

```
<spring:message code="header_order_edit" arguments="332321,My Client" />
```

In Java code, display it like this:

```
messageSource.getMessage("header_order_edit", new Object[] {"332321", "My Client"}, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())
```

Of course, for the Java code to work, you need to wire the bean you are using...

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

In both cases the result will look as follows:

```
Edit Order 332321 for customer My Client
```